# Method [validateResuired] does not exist

Tags: laravel-5

I got this error and I didn't find the best explication on google search 
Method [validateResuired] does not exist
I wrote a code as a TP to upload photos with laravel5

Comment: What code did you try so far ??

Comment: I created an interface 'PhotoGestionInterface' and a class 'PhotoGestion' contains this method public function save(UploadedFile $image)
 {
  $image->store(config('images.path'), 'public');
 } the controller has this method public function postForm(
  imageRequest $request, PhotoGestionInterface $photo )
 {

  $photo->save($request->image);
  return view('photo_ok');
 } and the request contains this rule 'image'=>'required|image'

Comment: Try with this rule `'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,gif,svg,pdf',` !!

Comment: I got same error

Comment: is there some other validation rules elsewhere, because most probablly there is a tippo in some rule instead of `required` !!

Comment: I applied the validation directly on controller $validator= Validator::make($request->all(), ['image'=>'required|image']);
  if($validator->fails()){
   return back()->withErroors($validator)->withInput();
  }else{
   $photo->save($request->image);
  } it worked, it appears that I had a problem in my request file

Comment: So is there any other problem ? i can help :)

Comment: No, thanks Maraboc